# Installing Redis on MAC 10.8.5 Not Working! Where is the DMG ? Undefined symbol -?*&!

Tags: redis

I am trying to install latest Redis on my Macbook Pro running 10.8.5  After downloading the tar ball, I am invited to make the project ....
Upon typing make:

```
 LINK redis-server
 Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
```

I realize Redis is awesome product, but man where is the DMG? I mean,  do you realize how easy it is to install mongodb?

For those interested in the gory details on my mac:

```
     unknownb8f6b11c7271:redis-2.8.19 Mac1$ make
 cd src && make all
 LINK redis-server
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
   "___atomic_add_fetch", referenced from:
     _zmalloc in zmalloc.o
     _zcalloc in zmalloc.o
     _zrealloc in zmalloc.o
  _zmalloc_used_memory in zmalloc.o
  _zmalloc_get_fragmentation_ratio in zmalloc.o
 "___atomic_sub_fetch", referenced from:
  _zrealloc in zmalloc.o
  _zfree in zmalloc.o
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see    invocation)
 make[1]: *** [redis-server] Error 1
 make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way to install Redis on OS X is using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/). Just install it and run:

```
brew install redis
```

This command install already compiled binaries to your system.

Comment: Don't forget to run `brew update` first to ensure you get the latest version

Answer (score 0):

Do a

`make distclean`

first. `make distclean` should fix this by removing the built hiredis.

The next `make` should build all again.

Answer (score 0):

[make distclean; CC=gcc make ] I use this command . it works for redis 5.0.6

Answer (score 0):

Using Homebrew it is quite easy to install-

- brew update
- brew install redis

To check

- redis-cli ping

if you are getting PONG
Then you are good to go(y)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while compile C++ project with redis api
BUT I'm using g++ to compile while you using cmake.

if one used g++ compile C++ with redis on Mac(M1), one can add

```
-lhreids
```

for project compiling.
It would work.